# Encrypted connection without SSLStream?

Tags: c#, encryption, tcp, data-protection

I need to encrypt the data that will be sent/received, client <> server and vice-versa.

Since I can't use SSLStream right now, I am looking for other alternatives.

While thinking about the alternatives I have, I got stucked on how would I send the data to the client in a way it can't be read/intercepted.

Here is how I thinked of doing it:

- Client/Server will have a RSA private key inside the application that will be loaded from a string to encrypt/decrypt the data received from the server.
- After the initial connection request, the server will send a session id along with a inner AES key/iv.
- From here on the client will communicate using both, the RSA and the AES.

I would like to hear from experienced people some new ideas or better ways to do what I need here which is:

Send encrypted data from client to server and vice-versa without using SSLStream and yet having a good level of security.

I understand that having the private key on the client is risk but I am yet to find a better solution.

Comment: Do you need to authenticate the client? Or why do you need a private key in it?

Comment: CodeInChaos I need the private key because it was the only way I could think of to send the initial connection encrypted to get the inner communication AES key. Otherwise anyone using wireshark and a good understanding of it would be able to grab the AES going on plain text. I do understand that they can steal break into my app to get the string with the cert but then I could make that a lot more difficult for them with obfuscation, and other methods.

Comment: why do you need to distribute a private key with the client? That defeats the purpose of RSA. Why can't the client generate a random keypair and connect to the server, encrypting the connection using the server's public key?

Comment: axel_c I dont see how that would be different from the above method except the fact I would not be able to further encrypt the data with an outer encryption on top of it.

Comment: I think you're not understanding how public key cryptography works here. I'll write an answer to explain my suggestion properly

Comment: axel_c I understand how it works but it would not make a difference here in both ways they would have to decompile my application to get the data that was what I was pointing out in the above answer. In the case of using just the public key and generating the AES from client side they could simple ignore the pub key and go straight for the AES as the received data would not have any outer encryption since the client only have the public key in which you can't decrypt the received that relying only on the AES.

Comment: If you don't need to authenticate the client, having the public key in the client and the private key in the server is enough. That way somebody reversing the client can't learn anything of interest, and the server is in a secure location.

Comment: CodeInChaos so you think only the AES is enough and I dont need to overthink the idea like I seem to be right now ? Yes the server is in secure location, I was just worried on how easy it would be intercepted the data or to get the key out of the client.

Comment: @Prix Where did I say that? I said put the RSA public key into the client, the RSA private key into the server, and use that to negotiate a symmetric session key. Just like SSL does it by default.

Comment: CodeInChaos yes but after that it will rely on the AES key only for the server encryption not ? thats why I asked the above, didnt mean to sound rude or anything.

Comment: The AES key randomly generated and distinct for each session. You rely on RSA for server authentication and key exchange.

Comment: But why can't you use SSL? It's designed to give you private, secure communication. There are plenty of pitfalls when creating a cryptographic protocol, and to be honest you don't really know what you're doing. So I strongly recommend using the work of security professionals instead of creating your own bad imitation of SSL.

Comment: CodeInChaos I appreciate your response, right now I can't use SSL for a set of reasons and I was planning to open a new question in regards those reason after this, I would have put it together but it would generate too much confusion and mix both issues hence why I did not. Hope you understand.

Comment: I agree with @CodeInChaos that home-grown "secure" protocols are not a good idea, and you should use SSL. If you absolutely must, then the models explained in the answers will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't use SSL, you can build poor man's SSL yourself:

The client knows a RSA public key, the server knows the corresponding private key.

To communicate the client creates a random session key that can be used with AES. It encrypts it with the RSA public key, and sends it to the server. It encrypts the rest of the communication with the AES session key.

The server decrypts the first message with the RSA private key, and thus gets the session key. It uses this key for the rest of the communication.

That way the client doesn't contain anything secret, but the communication itself is private. The main thing that's lacking with this scheme is client authentication.

You should also use different nonces/IVs for the server->client and the client->server stream. You might also want to add integrity checking(MACs).

Comment: right now, after the initial transaction for keys etc, the client is given X minutes to respond with user and password to authenticate with the system or else it is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is using a *shared secret*: something both the client and the server know, but no-one else does.

Public key SSL works on the premise that a certificate (and hence a key-pair) is locked to a particular server/domain which can be independently confirmed via a third party (the signing authority).

As soon as you get rid of this premise, you are open to man-in-the-middle attacks with public key encryption because you cannot guarantee who you are talking to (or at least you cannot guarantee someone is not intercepting/relaying your messages).

If you use a shared secret, you don't need public keys, certificates or anything else - but if any unauthorised party discovers your secret, you're screwed.

Comment: You don't need a CA to secure SSL. You can simply hardcode the public key into the client. Essentially you're using a single certificate as trusted root. That way you don't need a shared secret, but you 're not locked to a certain domain.

Comment: But if a attacker gets his/her hands on the program (during exchange) he/she can change the key in the program and play "man in the middle" - this is why you need the CA - if not the programm is the information you have to communicate on a secure channel first - and the serpent eats it's own tail....

Comment: You need the program from a secure source, yes. But CAs don't solve that problem. At one point or another, you need to get a list of trusted certificates into the client. The attacker could also simply change the program code to something insecure, even when you use a CA signed cert on the server.

Comment: True - but getting a OS from a known source is a far better bet (I think a man in the middle would be very unlikley here) ... but it's getting OT so never mind

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach:

-Server has a well-known public key and a private key no one knows (not even the clients)

-Client generates a 'handshake' packet and encrypts it with the server's public key. The handshake packet contains any initialisation/authentication stuff you need, plus a randomly generated passphrase + IV to use for AES encryption.

-Server decrypts handshake packet using its private key and now has access to the AES passphrase + IV. It responds with an 'ACK' packet indicating its ready.

-Now client can send data using the AES passphrase to encrypt symmetrically, and the server can decrypt, and vice versa.

There's no need for the client having any private key bundled with it. RSA is specifically designed for data exchange without the need for a shared key.

Comment: where to you need the clients public/private key?

Comment: @CarstenKönig yep, it was not necessary (I was initially thinking about encrypting the ACK packet with client's public key, but that's superfluous). I was just editing my answer to reflect that.

Comment: axel_c thanks for the response, I understand that, which was why I was saying on the comments of the main question "only the AES is enough and I dont need to overthink the idea" which I meant by that, that there would happen a initial encrypted data with the RSA and after that only the AES would act instead of having a shared priv key to maintain both "in/out" encrypted as a dummy RSA protection.